# css - Margin Left Right Auto Not Working Despite Inline-Block and Parent Element with Fixed Width

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to center a pair of buttons within a form. These buttons are wrapped in `<div>` which has `display: inline-block` set against it so the `<div>` is only as wide as the buttons. The parent to the `<div>` which is a `<form>` element has `fixed-width: 290px` set against it.

However, on the `<div>`, when I set `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto`, the `<div>` doesn't center itself within the `<form>`. I have even set `display: block` against the `<form>` element too to no avail.

What am I doing wrong?

HTML:

```
<form id="schemeForm">
    <!--Other HTML elements-->
    <div id="formButtons">
        <input type="button" value="Back" />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </div>
</form>
```

CSS:

```
#schemeForm {
    width: 290px;
    display: block;
}

#formButtons {
    display: inline-block; /*to make it only as wide as buttons*/
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Example Code Snippet:

```css
#schemeForm {
    width: 290px;
    display: block;
    background-color: black;
}

#formButtons {
    display: inline-block; /*to make it only as wide as buttons*/
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<form id="schemeForm">
    <!--Other HTML elements-->
    <div id="formButtons">
        <input type="button" value="Back" />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: _“What am I doing wrong?”_ - you are assuming auto margins would work on inline-block elements, which they simply do not.

Comment: @CBroe ahh forgive me, but I thought the purpose of inline-block was to preserve the properties of block elements? If that isn't the case then I have to assigned fixed values to the buttons before assigning a fixed width to the div then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to give text-align: center to #schemeForm

```
<html>
    <style>
        #schemeForm {
        width: 290px;
        display: block;
        background-color: black;
        text-align: center;
}

#formButtons {
        display: inline-block; /*to make it only as wide as buttons*/
        background-color: orange;
}
    </style>
<body>
    <form id="schemeForm">
        <div id="formButtons">
            <input type="button" value="Back" />
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep #formButtons `display: block` and set `text-align: center`.

```css
#schemeForm {
  width: 290px;
  display: block;
}

#formButtons {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<form id="schemeForm">
    <!--Other HTML elements-->
    <div id="formButtons">
        <input type="button" value="Back" />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you want `display:block;` instead of `display:inline-block;`